# Fileshare server infrastructure name

Tags: file-sharing, website

I'm currently developing a documents fileshare service, and it becomes more and more evident that my very basic configuration with a server from Plesk is insufficient for my needs. I.e. I'm starting 3-4 downloads on the server and loading the website on it is slow.

Basically, I'm not searching for direct company name nor for anyone making promotion of his services, but for the actual name of the type of infrastructure that is made to receive very heavy traffic - not just some requests to serve html pages - and that can handles millions of file transfer every months. I'm not thinking about designing the architecture myself, but just want to walk toward the good kind of services. So it's a 'definition' question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are all literally just static files you could use a CDN, Content Distribution Network - something like Akamai, CloudFront etc.